# Powershell get Multiple Value Property in List Format

Tags: powershell

Is it possible, to get a multiple string-values from an AD User property?

I have an property that contains various departments and want to get all departments, in list format.

Can I loop through this Array?

```
$bvsDepartments = Get-ADUser USER -Properties bvsDepartments | select bvsdepartments

output: 
bvsdepartments
--------------
{Value1, Value2, Value3,...}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'list format'? Array? String? Updating `| select -ExpandProperty bvsdepartments` will give you an array of values..

Comment: `$bvsDepartments.bvsDepartments[0]`, `$bvsDepartments.bvsDepartments[1]`, `$bvsDepartments.bvsDepartments[2]` and so on...

Comment: Thanks @JamesC. this is working fine!

Answer (score 1):

If you update your `select` with `ExpandProperty` this will give you an array of just the values rather than the property as an object.

```
$bvsDepartments = Get-ADUser USER -Properties bvsDepartments |
    select -ExpandProperty bvsdepartments
```